# HSV to color on android

Tags: android, hsv

I have an exception to change color of view by function HSVToColor,this is the code. I think the problem is in value of `Hue`, `Saturation` and `Value`.

```
    Tab_COLOR[0] =300; //pHue [0 .. 360)
    Tab_COLOR[1] =0.0f;//pSaturation [0...1]
    Tab_COLOR[2] =0.0f; //pValue [0...1]
    int couleur=Color.HSVToColor(Tab_COLOR);
    view1.setBackgroundColor(couleur);
```

Comment: Could you show the exception information? That might help.

Comment: `I have an exception` so where is the stacktrace?